# Calculating %changes with the By()

Tags: r

I am an inexperienced R user and have been struggling with the By() function and would appreciate your help. The task is simple, I have a longitudinal dataset (How do I declare one?) and need to calculate different metrics by ID. One of the the metrics is a simple percent change (that requires a lag, example below):

```
 ID         Date          Temp        %Change
 AAA    1/1/2003    0.749881714 NA
 AAA    1/2/2003    0.666661576 -0.110977687
 AAA    1/3/2003    0.773079935 0.159628759
 AAA    1/4/2003    0.62902364  -0.186340751
 AAA    1/5/2003    0.733312374 0.165794619
 BBB    1/1/2003    0.707339766 NA
 BBB    1/2/2003    0.764986529 0.081497982
 BBB    1/3/2003    0.662201467 -0.134361925
 BBB    1/4/2003    0.774451765 0.169510798  
 BBB    1/5/2003    0.50829093  -0.343676453
 CCC    1/1/2003    0.836836215 NA
 CCC    1/2/2003    0.837136823 0.00035922
 CCC    1/3/2003    0.809016624 -0.033590924
 CCC    1/4/2003    0.690277509 -0.146769685
 CCC    1/5/2003    0.796357069 0.153676686
```

Intuitively I understand the use of By(), but haven't been able to produce the correct result (%Change) using a data.frame that contains $ID, $Date, and $Temp. Any suggestions in how to achieve the desired %Change would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mateo.  This is a really nice question with good sample data.

Comment: I'm guess that was meant to ask about the `by` function. Correct capitalization (or "not" in this case) is crucial in R.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a combination of `plyr` to handle the group by operation on ID and `quantmod` has a function for the percentage change named `Delt`.

```
require(plyr)
require(quantmod)

> ddply(dat, "ID", transform,  DeltaCol = Delt(Temp))
    ID     Date      Temp    X.Change Delt.1.arithmetic
1  AAA 1/1/2003 0.7498817          NA                NA
2  AAA 1/2/2003 0.6666616 -0.11097769     -0.1109776868
3  AAA 1/3/2003 0.7730799  0.15962876      0.1596287574
4  AAA 1/4/2003 0.6290236 -0.18634075     -0.1863407501
5  AAA 1/5/2003 0.7333124  0.16579462      0.1657946178
6  BBB 1/1/2003 0.7073398          NA                NA
7  BBB 1/2/2003 0.7649865  0.08149798      0.0814979813
8  BBB 1/3/2003 0.6622015 -0.13436192     -0.1343619242
9  BBB 1/4/2003 0.7744518  0.16951080      0.1695107963
10 BBB 1/5/2003 0.5082909 -0.34367645     -0.3436764522
11 CCC 1/1/2003 0.8368362          NA                NA
12 CCC 1/2/2003 0.8371368  0.00035922      0.0003592196
13 CCC 1/3/2003 0.8090166 -0.03359092     -0.0335909235
14 CCC 1/4/2003 0.6902775 -0.14676969     -0.1467696849
15 CCC 1/5/2003 0.7963571  0.15367669      0.1536766860
```

Alternatively, you can skip the `plyr` bit, calculate the Delta for the entire data.frame and then update the first row for each ID. There are lots of good ideas about selecting the first row of a data.frame based off of an identifier [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier/7889#7889). Something like this would probably work:

```
dat$Delta <- Delt(dat$Temp)
dat[ diff(c(0,dat$ID)) != 0, 5] <- NA
```

On a related note, if anyone can explain why Delta doesn't seem to accept my plea to give it a reasonable column name, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting combo. I thought one has to have an xts structure for quantmode to work. Also, have been wondering how to pin point first/last obs of a data.frame, the link is extremely useful.

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP specifically asked about using `by()` I thought I'd provide an answer the illustrates it's use.

First you write a function that acts on each 'piece' of the data frame:

```
myFun <- function(x){
n <- nrow(x)
x$Change <- c(NA,diff(x$Temp) / head(x$Temp,n-1))
x
}
```

I've used the base functions `diff` to calculate the sequential differences in `Temp` and then since the resulting vector has length n-1, we use `head` to divide the the differences by all but the last Temp value. (I did this just to work `head` in since it's handy; there are lots of other ways to do that).

Then the `by` call:

```
by(dat,dat$ID,FUN=myFun)
```

If you want to put all the pieces back together again, we can use `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind,by(dat,dat$ID,FUN=myFun))
```

Comment: +1, nice answer. Every time I try and use the aggregating functions in base R, I end up feeling like I'm playing with a dull, rusty spork.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think about the diff function....just getting used to do.call()!

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested output is not "%change"  (but rather fractional difference) while this illustrates a method getting "percent of original" using the initial value as the basis for the change:

```
> dat$pctTemp <-  unlist(
            tapply(dat$Temp, dat$ID, function(x) c(NA, 100*x[-1]/x[1]) )
                        )
> dat
    ID     Date      Temp   pctTemp
1  AAA 1/1/2003 0.7498817        NA
2  AAA 1/2/2003 0.6666616  88.90223
3  AAA 1/3/2003 0.7730799 103.09358
4  AAA 1/4/2003 0.6290236  83.88305
5  AAA 1/5/2003 0.7333124  97.79041
6  BBB 1/1/2003 0.7073398        NA
7  BBB 1/2/2003 0.7649865 108.14980
8  BBB 1/3/2003 0.6622015  93.61858
snipped
```

If you want interval change, you can divide diff(x) by the prceding values

```
> dat$pctTemp <-  unlist(tapply(dat$Temp, dat$ID, function(x) c(NA, 100*diff(x)/x[-length(x)]) )  )
> dat
    ID     Date      Temp      pctTemp
1  AAA 1/1/2003 0.7498817           NA
2  AAA 1/2/2003 0.6666616 -11.09776868
3  AAA 1/3/2003 0.7730799  15.96287574
4  AAA 1/4/2003 0.6290236 -18.63407501
5  AAA 1/5/2003 0.7333124  16.57946178
6  BBB 1/1/2003 0.7073398           NA
7  BBB 1/2/2003 0.7649865   8.14979813
snipped
```

Comment: Interesting and useful comments and extensions. Thank a lot Chase, Joran and DWin!