# R data.table Return calculation and set()

Tags: r, data.table

I am sure I am missing something simple, but how do I calculate daily returns using data.tables in R?

Let's say I have a data.table like:

`DT <- data.table(ticker=rep(letters,each=5), priceA=runif(5*26^2), priceB=runif(5*26^2))`

How to I form a new column with the respective returns of price for each ticker?

By returns I mean the normal percentage returns. That is, the second value of priceA for ticker a minus the previous one for the same ticker and this divided by the previous one.

Given the example with the columns ticker, priceA and priceB I should get the column returnsA as in:

```
      ticker     priceA     priceB  returnsA
   1:      a 0.63519775 0.04784728 
   2:      a 0.01530738 0.34917328  -0.97590
   3:      a 0.28601406 0.12307475  17.68472 
   4:      a 0.77851212 0.47829863  1.721937
   5:      a 0.84078779 0.23491432  0.079993
```

Also, how do I use `set()` instead of `:=` to make sth like

`DT[, newprice := priceA * priceB]`

?

Thank you! :)

Comment: For `set`, maybe `DT[,newprice:=NA]; set(DT,j=4L,value=DT[['priceA']]*DT[['priceB']])` You haven't defined "returns" yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what I wanted for set(). I have updated my question and added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this works:

```
set.seed(42)
DT <- data.table(
  ticker=rep(letters,each=5),
  priceA=runif(5*26^2),
  priceB=runif(5*26^2))

DT[,paste('returns',LETTERS[1:2],sep=''):={
  lapply(.SD,function(x){
    old <- head(x,-1)
    new <- tail(x,-1)
    c(NA,(new-old)/old)
  })
},by=ticker,.SDcols=grep('^price',names(DT))]
```

The result (for this seed value) is

```
      ticker    priceA    priceB    returnsA   returnsB
   1:      a 0.9148060 0.7956245          NA         NA
   2:      a 0.9370754 0.9314941  0.02434327  0.1707710
   3:      a 0.2861395 0.6269996 -0.69464620 -0.3268883
   4:      a 0.8304476 0.1666758  1.90224707 -0.7341691
   5:      a 0.6417455 0.6483800 -0.22722939  2.8900659
  ---                                                  
3376:      z 0.2887293 0.3473923 -0.54132570 -0.3514041
3377:      z 0.9013438 0.1788842  2.12176058 -0.4850656
3378:      z 0.3126429 0.7648157 -0.65313686  3.2754788
3379:      z 0.8791381 0.1300418  1.81195584 -0.8299698
3380:      z 0.8160158 0.8159330 -0.07180019  5.2743905
```

To use `set` in your example:

```
DT[,newprice:=NA]
set(DT,j=ncol(DT),value=DT[['priceA']]*DT[['priceB']])
```

Also, there are packages designed for dealing with returns and such, as seen here: [Calculating %changes with the By()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511146/calculating-changes-with-the-by)

Comment: So, it wasn't so simple. :) Thank you very much. For anybody interested, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937165/using-dynamic-column-names-in-data-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508482/what-does-sd-stand-for-in-data-table-in-r are helpful for understanding .SDcols

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, actually `.SDcols` is not strictly needed if your DT looks exactly like this (since `.SD`'s columns would default to every column except "ticker", because it is in the `by`). I used it here because (1) if you ran the operation twice in a row without it, you'd find weird results; and... well (2) it's useful to know about, along with `grep`, `head`, `[[`, etc. if they're new to you or someone else coming across this question :) Anyways, those are good references you've found there.

Comment: I am trying to understand your working solution and I am trying to modify it. Suppose I want to use Delt() from library(quantmod) that calculates the returns instead of your `function(x)`. Could I ask how should I do this?

Comment: @user2383408 Despite linking to it, I don't know the quantmod package. Maybe you should post another question...?

Comment: Asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923028/r-using-quantmods-delt-in-a-data-table Thank you very much, Frank, you saved my day! :)